# javafx font size of chart title and axis label

Tags: java, javafx

I am using javafx to plot bar chart and pie chart. I need to:

1. Change the font size of the x-axis label in bar chart
2. Change the font size of the bar chart title
3. Change the font size of the pie chart title

For bar chart I am using

```
xAxis.tickLabelFontProperty().set(Font.font(fontSize));
```

which only changes the font size of the text(units) on xaxis,  but doenst change the x axis label

Similarly I am using

```
chart.setStyle("-fx-font-size: " + fontSize + "px;");
```

to change the label of pies in pie chart. It does change the size of the title of pie chart but not in same ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind I was able to change it using

```
chart.setStyle("-fx-font-size: " + fontSize + "px;");
```

but still the title font size doesnt change in expected ratio. But I can work live with it